# Regex needed for this string in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I need a regex which can search in the below string

Version updated to 13.0.1700.943 by the build system. ***NO_CI***

Output needed 13.0.1700.943

Comment: You need to give more details... are you looking for a numeric field (numbers and decimals)?  What if there are more than one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regex

`(\d+\.){3}\d+`

Breakdown

`(\d+\.)`: This is the first capturing group. It finds one or more digits followed by a dot. Note that in regex, this dot has to be escaped.

`{3}`: This quantifier means, it will match the previous expression three times. In your example, you had three such instances

`\d+`: The last number does not have a dot after it, so we write it after the previous group.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Richard Hamiltons answer (which would also match an IPv4)
the quantifier's can also limit the number of required places to match exactly your example

```
\d{2}\.\d\.\d{4}\.\d{3}
```

For a range you can use `\d{1,2}` to match one or two digits.